# Push different objects (object1, object2, and object3) to array using for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently working on a project that fetches data from an open-source API. My problem is, the API includes objects that needs to be put into an array. They are named: `strIngredients1, strIngredients2, strIngredients3`, so on and so forth... I want to put them into a single array named `ingredients`, using a for loop if possible, but I honestly don't know what to do :(

I still haven't tried anything since, again, I don't even know what logic I'll be implementing for this task.

EDIT: To make things more clear, let's say I have three objects named `obj1`, `obj2`, and `obj3`. I want to push all of them into one single array called `arr`. The normal way of doing this is of course by manually adding them into the array:

```
// Manual way

var arr = []
var obj1 = {}
var obj2 = {}
var obj3 = {}

arr.push(obj1, obj2, obj3)
```

What I want to accomplish is to do this but using a for loop instead. Kinda like this.

```
// For Loop

for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    arr.push('obj'+i)
}
```

But of course, this would only push strings not the objects.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you check `Object.values()`?

Comment: I think adding an actual sample of the api's response will be much helpful

Comment: It would help your question if you added an example of the JSON from which you want to extract those objects rather than have everyone guess and write incorrect answers. @spadletskys

Comment: Is the API request you're making to www.themealdb.com ?

Answer (score 0):

we need more context but if i understood correctly, the objects from the fetch call look like this:

```
[
  { ingredients: [val1, val2, ... ,valN] },
  { ingredients: [val1, val2, ... ,valN] }
]
```

and you want to stores all the ingredients in a single array

```
const ingredients = [] // all ingredients in here?
```

If that is the case, try:

```
const ingredients = []

for(const obj of objArray){
  ingredients.push(...obj[ingredients])
}
```

What happens here is all the ingredients of each object get spread into the push function, which pushes every value into your ingredients array. Hope that could help! If not, please provide more context to your question.

Comment: Have you taken a look on my updated question? I explained the problem more in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In 'this' you have all your variables

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    arr.push(this['obj'+i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways:

First:

```
const arr = []
const obj1 = { a: 1 }
const obj2 = { b: 2 }
const obj3 = { c: 3 }

// need nestedObjects - for group objects to push

const nestedObjects = [obj1, obj2, obj3]

nestedObjects.forEach(o => arr.push(o))
```

Second:

Use global context this in fucntion

```
function dd() {
  const arr = []
  this.obj1 = { a: 1 }
  this.obj2 = { b: 2 }
  this.obj3 = { c: 3 }

  for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        const value = this[`obj${i}`]
        if (value) arr.push()
  }
    
}
dd()
```

if you variables in global context? you can not take that from loop

```
var arr = []
var obj1 = {}
var obj2 = {}
var obj3 = {}
```